# I got an error while creating virtualenv. It thows cmd not defined error

Tags: virtualenv, python-venv

```
└─$ python3 -m venv venv
Error: name 'cmd' is not defined
                                                       
┌──()-[~/Documents/Software Development/DjangoAuth/simplejwt]
└─$ source venv/bin/activate
source: no such file or directory: venv/bin/activate
```

It used to work fine on my other laptop while I just freshly installed new OS here, it throwing an odd error.

Answer (score 3):

[This bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1026268) (found by [search](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&pws=0&q=%22Error%3A+name+cmd+is+not+defined%22)) suggests you don't have `python-venv` package installed. Install it:

```
sudo apt-get install -y python3-venv
```

Comment: ```Reading package lists... Done

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3.10-venv : Depends: python3.10 (= 3.10.8-3) but 3.10.9-1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
``` I got this error

Comment: @rlopxhan21 `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y python3.10-venv`

Comment: Got the same error

Answer (score -1):

The error message is due to a conflict in the versions of Python installed on my system. The package python3.10-venv depends on version 3.10.8-3 of Python, but version 3.10.9-1 is to be installed.

To resolve this issue, I tried the following:

- Check the version of Python I have installed by running the command python3 --version.
- If I have a version of Python other than 3.10.8-3, I tried uninstalling it and installing version 3.10.8-3 instead.
- Once I have installed the correct version of Python, I  install the python3-venv package again using the sudo apt-get install -y python3-venv command and it worked.

Thanks all who helped!